# Using OData with the Repository Pattern

Tags: design-patterns, repository, odata

I have created a database (SQL Server 2008 Express), and created some LINQ to SQL entities (called LinqEntitiesDataContext) on top using the OR Designer in Visual Studio 2010. I've then created a Repository class and associated IRepository interface, containing a bunch of nice and simple CRUD methods that provide meaningful access to the data entities. For example, there's a method:

```
IQueryable<User> QueryUsersByType(UserTypeEnum userType)
```

and another:

```
void CreateUserWithDefaultType(User user)
```

Now I want to make this repository available "across the wire" and want to use WCF Data Services (OData) to provide access. But every example of OData I've seen ends up providing direct access to the entities themselves (e.g. the Users entity) They do this by making the data context class implement IUpdatable and then create a WCF Data Service that references this data context class. In my case, that would mean making LinqEntitiesDataContext IUpdatable and using it as the service type - which completely avoids using my Repository class.

I get the feeling that I need to make the data service expose my repository:

```
DataService<Repository>  // *Not* DataService<LinqEntitiesDataContext>
```

but then I'll need to make my Repository implement IUpdatable, avoiding the calls to my existing update methods (e.g. CreateUserWithDefaultType)

What am I missing here? Is there a good example of how to do this right, exposing the Repository layer rather than the entity layer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think @Bull was on the right track here, but want to build out an answer a little bit more.

As he said, OData is primarily designed to work with entities, not predefined methods. For instance, to achieve the first of your examples you would just want to expose an IQueryable of User, which will allow any OData client to form URLs such as `http://yourdomain/Users?$filter=UserType eq Administrator`. If you were using the WCF Data Services client, there is a LINQ provider that would allow you to do something like `context.Users.Where(u => u.UserType == "Administrator")`. (Also, please note that WCF Data Services doesn't currently support enums in our service models.)

Similarly, the second method would typically just be a POST to `http://yourdomain/Users` (the same IQueryable of User that we saw in the first example) and you would either set the default type on the model or in the database.

If you really do want to use your repository, you would probably be best off handling the full custom data service provider as described in Alex's blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2010/01/07/data-service-providers-getting-started.aspx

Final point - we do hope to make our providers public in the near future; this would greatly simplify what it is you're trying to achieve here. We'll count this post as another ref count for the importance of that particular feature. :)

HTH,
Mark

Comment: Hmmm, so this means I can't implement a nice clean interface to my data model just once and have service consumers benefit from that. Instead, each component in my business logic layer will have to work at an entity level, applying filters, expanding foreign keys, implementing paging, etc. Can I use Service Operations to do what I want, or will this end up being a bit of a mess?!

Comment: Some of the things you want to do can definitely be done at the server side. Paging is trivial on the server side if you're working with the EF provider, and it's not too hard otherwise. Pre-applying filters and expanding foreign keys is possible, you might just have to work harder to get there. Service Ops will probably be able to do everything you want, but it may wind up a mess. Moral of the story: we need to prioritize those public providers.

Comment: Ok, not what I wanted to hear but thanks for your feedback Mark. I'll push on with OData as the interface between our architecture layers as it fits the bill in other ways.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the picture. OData is there to expose your entities as feeds. Odata is also called WCF Data services and the right place to get the basic picture about ODATA/WCF Data services is here:

1. Quick start tutorials from msdn http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668796
2. Exposing data as service. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728286

Comment: Just a couple of minor corrections to this answer - OData isn't ONLY there to expose entities as feeds, but that's definitely the most common use case. Also, WCF Data Services is Microsoft's implementation of OData (a protocol). Minor nit, but OData is headed for standardization whereas WCF Data Services will not be standardized. (It will just implement a standard.)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using both WebApi 2 endpoints for custom api calls for all storedprocedure and functions when needed heavy lift of data from db and then OData v3 endpoints for all other normal tables so that I dont worry much about filteration and query paramter sent via api calls.